# Codeacademy like effect when user clicks "Get started" button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to implement a similar effect as the one on codeacademy (http://www.codecademy.com/) when the user clicks the get started button. So basically focus on a single div and shade out the rest of the page.

I am not asking for code but for the method. I've tried to change the opacity of the rest of the page except from the div I want to focus on but with no success.

Comment: What have you tried, examples? Not really a question suited for stackoverflow.

Comment: I tried to change the opacity of the rest of the page except from the div I want to focus on. How come is not suited?

Comment: You would know that if you read the FAQ.

Comment: I am a SO user for quite a while + I have read the FAQ but still cannot understand why. I am gonna delete the question since it didn't get much love but please let me know what is wrong with it so I will not repeat the same mistake. Simple as that

Comment: Read the following: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Comment: Where is the **programming** problem? You asked how one thing is done on a webpage, that is NOT an programming problem. That is more a lack of searching skills on your part. A good thing when asking a question in on SO is explaining a problem, and showing what you've tried so far with code examples and what you want the result to be.

Comment: @GeorgeEracleous point is, you did not try anything (or you didn't posted your trials and failures). You just say that you would like to have something that you saw on another website, on your website. we're here to help when programmer struggle, but we're not a group of people that you will say your requirements and we'll do it. Show us your efforts on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the css

```
.dimmer {
   background-color: #000;
   opacity: 0.4;
   z-index: 999;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   display: block;

}

#frame-that-does-not-dim {
   z-index: 99999;
}
```